# How do I access the boot menu of a Lenovo Yoga 710?

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

I've tried `Fn+F12`, `Fn+F2`, and `Fn+F1` as suggested on [this forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-S-Series-ThinkPad-Yoga/Yoga-15-Thinkpad-Boot-menu-How-do-I-reach-it/td-p/3779525), and doing the hard shutdown described in [this article](http://blog.lenovo.com/en/blog/how-to-enter-the-bios-setup-utility-or-boot-menu-with-windows-8-1/), to no avail. How do I access the BIOS setup menu on this laptop?

Comment: See this video....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpzB9B8zkIU&vl=en

Comment: That video is for a different model. See the picture in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some articles mention a "Novo button" next to the power button, but it turns out that this laptop's "Novo button" is actually inside a small pinhole on the left side of the computer. The pinhole is marked with an arrow pointing left in the shape of an arch. Use a SIM card pin (or a piece of pencil lead) to push the button as soon as the boot screen appears, and you'll be provided with the option to enter the BIOS settings or boot menu.

[image: the position of the pinhole]